# How to capture stdout and sterr AND proper piped exit status in Shell command?

Tags: bash, shell-script, pipe, exit-status

I want to be able to do the following:

```
command 2>&1 | shell_script.sh "subject line"
```

Where the stdout and sterr of running `command` will be piped to `shell_script.sh` for sending as the body of an email.  The thing that I want to get is the exit status of `command 2>&1` so that I can append the proper job status to the email subject.  With the current implementation, when `command 2>&1` is piped, the `${PIPESTATUS[0]}` is always set to `0`.  If I remove the `2>&1`, however, then the stderr output doesn't get piped into the email body.  Been playing with several different variations but still can't figure it out.

The following is my `shell_script.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
SUBJ="$@"
read EMAIL_BODY
jobsuccess=${PIPESTATUS[0]}

if [ $jobsuccess -eq 0 ]  # Job succeeded
then
        echo $EMAIL_BODY | mail -s "$SUBJ Success" my@email.com
else
        echo $EMAIL_BODY | mail -s "$SUBJ Fail" my@email.com
fi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

subject="subject line"

tmpfile=$(mktemp)
trap 'rm -f "$tmpfile"' EXIT

if command >"$tmpfile" 2>&1; then
    subject+=" Success"
else
    subject+=" Failure"
fi

mail -s "$subject" my@email.com <"$tmpfile"
```

So, save the output to a temporary file, then mail the file.  Set the subject line according to the exit status of the command before sending. No need for two scripts.

You can't access `PIPESTATUS` inside the pipeline as the pipeline hasn't yet finished executing. Also, the external script would not have access to it in any case as it's running in its own environment.

What is also not possible is to be piped the input from a generic command, and then act on the exit states of that command.  There is no way to access the exit status of a previous command in a pipeline from within the pipeline itself.

What you *could* do is to wrap the command in code that outputs a piece of text, signifying success or failure.  This text would be piped together with the rest of the data (by necessity, as an extra piece of info at the end):

```bash
{ if command 2>&1; then echo SUCCESS; else echo FAILURE; } | shell_script.sh
```

... with `shell_script.sh` being

```bash
#!/bin/bash

subject="subject line"

tmpfile=$(mktemp)
trap 'rm -f "$tmpfile"' EXIT

cat >"$tmpfile"

if [[ $(tail -n 1 "$tmpfile") == *SUCCESS* ]]; then
    subject+=" Success"
else
    subject+=" Failure"
fi

sed '$d' "$tmpfile" | mail -s "$subject" me@mail.com
```

This still has to save the data to a temporary file to access the last line of it (this is done using `cat` which reads standard input by default).  It then decides whether it was a success or not and sets the subject accordingly.  The data with the last line removed is then mailed.

Another option would be to run the mailer script *after* running the command (commands in a pipeline are executing concurrently), and then simply pass the exit status, which then would be available, as a command line argument:

```bash
command >command.log 2>&1
shell_script.sh "$?" <command.log
rm -f command.log
```

and the script would look like

```bash
#!/bin/bash

subject="subject line"

if [[ $1 == 0 ]]; then
    subject+=" Success"
else
    subject+=" Failure"
fi

mail -s "$subject" my@email.com
```

In this case, the data to be mailed is passed on standard input, which the `mail` utility will read by default (just like `cat` did in the previous example).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I'm writing it as an external script because ``command`` is meant to be any generic command/job I feed in.  How would I change your code so that it's compatible to be run in the ``command | shell_script.sh "subject line"`` framework?

Comment: @nwly See updated answer. You simply can't have the exact pipeline that you propose as there is absolutely no way for the shell script to know whether the command failed or not.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.